# python if to much any sentence start with word ABC

Tags: python

I'm working on python script and i need some advice..

I have the below  output

```
{'port': 'Hu1/0/16', 'status': 'down', 'protocol': 'down', 'descrip': 'ABC-01'}, 
{'port': 'Hu1/0/17', 'status': 'up', 'protocol': 'up', 'descrip': 'ABC-02'}, 
{'port': 'Hu1/0/18', 'status': 'up', 'protocol': 'up', 'descrip': 'A-01'}, 
{'port': 'Hu1/0/19', 'status': 'up', 'protocol': 'up', 'descrip': 'EE-01'},
```

my target from the output above i need to show only the ports that 'descrip' start with 'ABC' as a result the final output should be as below

```
{'port': 'Hu1/0/16', 'status': 'down', 'protocol': 'down', 'descrip': 'ABC-01'}, 
{'port': 'Hu1/0/17', 'status': 'up', 'protocol': 'up', 'descrip': 'ABC-02'},
```

My code as below

```
 for i in range(0,3):
         if show[i]['descrip'] =='ABC':
              print(show[i])
         else:
              print ("No much Found ")
```

When i run the script nothing appear as below output

```
No much Found
```

Any advice plz .. Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of `if show[i]['descrip'] == 'ABC':`, maybe try `if show[i]['descrip'].startswith('ABC'):`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.startswith()` property

```py
for i in range(0, 3):
    if show[i]['descrip'].startswith('ABC'):
        print(show[i])
```

Output:

```
{'port': 'Hu1/0/16', 'status': 'down', 'protocol': 'down', 'descrip': 'ABC-01'}
{'port': 'Hu1/0/17', 'status': 'up', 'protocol': 'up', 'descrip': 'ABC-02'}
```

---

##### Addition to the answer:

To check if matches are found or not, initialize a boolean and set its value to `True` whenever there's a match
Use `len(show)` in `range()` function which in this case is `4`. Using `range(0, 3)` doesn't iterate over the last element as the second argument is exclusive

```py
matches_found = False
for i in range(0, len(show)):
    if show[i]['descrip'].startswith('ABC'):
        matches_found = True
        print(show[i])

if not matches_found:
    print('No matches found')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dicts (output) are in a list you can do a list comprehension and a .startswith() check on each row's descrip value.

```py
outputs = [
{'port': 'Hu1/0/16', 'status': 'down', 'protocol': 'down', 'descrip': 'ABC-01'}, 
{'port': 'Hu1/0/17', 'status': 'up', 'protocol': 'up', 'descrip': 'ABC-02'}, 
{'port': 'Hu1/0/18', 'status': 'up', 'protocol': 'up', 'descrip': 'A-01'}, 
{'port': 'Hu1/0/19', 'status': 'up', 'protocol': 'up', 'descrip': 'EE-01'}, 
]

onlyabc = [row for row in outputs if row['descrip'].startswith('ABC')]
print(onlyabc)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

```
def process(data):
 for i in range (len(data)):
  if (data[i]["descrip"].startswith("ABC")):
   print(data[i])
```

Or if u want to group it,

```
def process(data):
 arr = []
 for i in range (len(data)):
     if (data[i]["descrip"].startswith("ABC")):
        arr.append(data[i])
 print(arr)
```